# Convert this SQL query to Laravel?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

Hi i have troubles converting this query to Laravel, my query works fine, but idk how to convert to a laravel query:

`select p.id, p.enunciado, p.created_at, c.categoria, s.categoria
from preguntas_seleccion p, categorias c,sub_categorias s
where p.categorias_id = c.id and p.sub_categorias_id = s.id and c.id = s.categorias_id`

Comment: Do you have the models set up?

Comment: Why don't you give the raw query as is using `DB::select`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the last condition? Anyway, it should work like this (untested code!):

```
   $query =  \DB::table('preguntas_seleccion as p')->select("p.id","p.enunciado","p.created_at", "c.categoria","s.categoria");
        $query->join('categorias', function($join)
        {
            $join->on('p.categorias_id', '=', 'c.id');
            $join->on('c.id', '=', "s.categorias_id");
        });
        $query->join('sub_categorias as s', 'p.sub_categorias_id', '=', 's.id');
        return $query->get();
```